# how to upload multiple images to firebase storage and store all urls in an array to firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, storage

here is my code I can get all Links but I am not able to store them in an array and send them to Firebase
[here is the codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ8va.png)
[here are the codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g3Zl.png)

looking forward for the answer thankyou

Comment: Please paste your code as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your uploadImageAsPromise function:

```
// make the function async 
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  const fileUploads = files.map(file => storageRef.child(file.name).put(file));

const uploadRequests = await Promise.all(fileUploads)
      
  const fileURLReqs = uploadRequests.map(f => f.ref.getDownloadURL())
  const fileUrls = await Promise.all(fileURLReqs)
```

fileUrls will be array of download URLs.

If you need to show progress of each upload then you run a loop on fileUploads array and use the "task.on()" on each element.

Comment: I'll fix the formatting asap when I get on computer :')